# Connection refused! Is selenium server started nightwatch on edge

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I have create a project. It is a vue.js application. There is a small set of unit tests (jest) and an end-to-end test (night watch).

When I try and run the end-to-end test using npm i get:

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ value:
   { message: 'Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@16b328bc\nBuild info: version: \'3.12.0\', revision: \'7c6e0b3\', time: \'2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z\'\nSystem info: host:
\'SYNERGY02\', ip: \'192.168.1.41\', os.name: \'Windows 10\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'10.0\', java.version: \'1.8.0_181\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown',
     error: 'session not created' },
  status: 33 }
```

I don't know what I could be missing. This has me stuck for over a week

Here is the nightwatch.json

> locate path in D:\xxx\test\bin\myedgedriver.exe
>
> locate path in D:\xxx\test\e2e\nightwatch.conf.js

```
require('babel-register')
var config = require('../../config')

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      "webdriver.edge.driver": "../bin/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path,
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || config.dev.port)
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },
    edge: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'edge',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        nativeEvents: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my window ver.

```
1803 (os build 17134.285)
```

my edgewebdriver ver.

```
Release 17134
Version: 6.17134 | Edge version supported: 17.17134
```

my edge brower ver.

```
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
```

finally my nightwatch from package.json ver.

```
 "nightwatch": "^0.9.12"
"selenium-server": "^3.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ value: { message: 'Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@16b328bc\nBuild info: version: \'3.12.0\', revision: \'7c6e0b3\', time: \'2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'SYNERGY02\', ip: \'192.168.1.41\', os.name: \'Windows 10\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'10.0\', java.version: \'1.8.0_181\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown', error: 'session not created' }, status: 33 }
```

...implies that there was an error connecting to the *Selenium Server*.

The *Selenium Server* logs would have given us some more leads to exactly went wrong.

However it seems there is discrepency between your target *Test Environment* and the existing *Test Environment* underneath as follows:

- You have mentioned:

  - my nightwatch from package.json ver: `"selenium-server": "^3.0.1"`
- But your error trace log mentions:

  - `version: \'3.12.0\'` of `time: \'2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z\`

### Solution

- Ensure that your *Test Environment* is configured with a unique set of *Selenium Server* binaries.
- Before you start the `@Tests` ensure **Selenium Server** is started through the following command:

  ```
  java -jar <path_to>/selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar
  ```
- If you want to use native events functionality, indicate this on the command line with the option:

  ```
  -Dwebdriver.enable.native.events=1
  ```
- To get help on other command line options, execute:

  ```
  java -jar <path_to>/selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -help
  ```
- You can find a similar detailed discussion in:

  - ['Connection refused! Is selenium server started?\n' while running Nightwatch.js tests against Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162892/connection-refused-is-selenium-server-started-n-while-running-nightwatch-js)