# "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?" error in VueJS Nightwatch E2E tests using ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, vue.js, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I have a VueJS app that has the default Nightwatch E2E tests. I just spent some time getting user accounts and auth set up. After doing so, when I try to run my E2E tests, they fail mysteriously. Here's the command line output I get:

```
code/premium-poker-tools [master●] » npm run e2e

> premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e /Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools
> node test/e2e/runner.js

> Starting dev server...

Starting to optimize CSS...
> Listening at http://localhost:8080

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  58502
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools/test/e2e/specs/hit-calculator.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".


  player
1
2
3
    1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) player "before all" hook:
     Connection refused! Is selenium server started?





npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 10
npm ERR! premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e: `node test/e2e/runner.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 10
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamzerner/.npm/_logs/2019-05-23T19_47_08_016Z-debug.log
code/premium-poker-tools [master●] »
```

And here is `/Users/adamzerner/.npm/_logs/2019-05-27T17_44_07_557Z-debug.log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.11.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'e2e' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v11.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pree2e', 'e2e', 'poste2e' ]
5 info lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~pree2e: premium-poker-tools@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: premium-poker-tools@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/bin
9 verbose lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: CWD: /Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools
10 silly lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: Args: [ '-c', 'node test/e2e/runner.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: Returned: code: 10  signal: null
12 info lifecycle premium-poker-tools@1.0.0~e2e: Failed to exec e2e script
13 verbose stack Error: premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e: `node test/e2e/runner.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 10
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid premium-poker-tools@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools
16 verbose Darwin 18.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.11.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "e2e"
18 verbose node v11.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 10
22 error premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e: `node test/e2e/runner.js`
22 error Exit status 10
23 error Failed at the premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 e2e script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 10, true ]
```

For one, the `Connection refused! Is selenium server started?` error seems wrong. Above that it says `Starting selenium server... started - PID:  58502`, and I see a **Chrome** browser pop up very briefly and then immediately close.

Here is the code for the `before` block in question:

```
before(function (browser, done) {
  console.log(1);
  equityCalculator = browser.page['equity-calculator']();
  console.log(2);
  equityCalculator.navigate();
  console.log(3);
  browser.pause(20000);
  equityCalculator
    .waitForElementVisible('@app', 50000, function () {
      console.log(4);
      browser.resizeWindow(1440, 852, function () {
        console.log(5);
        done();
      });
    })
  ;
});
```

I've been trying to pin down where the problem occurs, but I'm having a lot of trouble. `1`, `2`, and `3` get logged out, but not `4` or `5`, so that helps. But if `3` gets logged out, why isn't `browser.pause(20000)` working?

I've also been trying to mess around in my actual code to see where the issue is. I tried some `alert` statements in `main.js` to try to pinpoint the issue:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
alert(1);

window.$ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

alert(2);

import Vue from 'vue';
import store from '@/store';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import monkeyPatches from '@/services/monkey-patches';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

alert(3);

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    config.withCredentials = true;
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  store: store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});

// if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
//   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').catch(function() {
//     console.log('Service worker registration failed.');
//   });
// }
```

But weirdly, `alert(1)` isn't even working. So I feel at a loss. From what I understand, the top of `main.js` is the "beginning" of a Vue app, and if it's not even reaching that point, what is going on? `equityCalculator = browser.page['equity-calculator']();` and `equityCalculator.navigate();` seem pretty standard. Here's a snippet of the page object:

```
module.exports = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/equity-calculator',
  elements: {
    'app': '#app',
```

When I start my dev server and go to that url, it totally works. And my E2E tests were all working perfectly before I implemented user accounts and auth, I didn't change this file, and yet now I'm having the issue.

I'm not sure where I can go from here. Help!

---

Update:

Excerpt from `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "chromedriver": "^2.45.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.21",
    "selenium-server": "^3.141.59",
  },
}
```

Here's `nightwatch.conf.js`:

```
require('babel-register')
let config = require('../../config')

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],
  page_objects_path: 'test/e2e/page-objects',
  globals_path: 'test/e2e/globals.js',
  test_runner : 'mocha',

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || config.dev.port),
        handStrings: [
          'aa', 'aks', 'aqs', 'ajs', 'ats', 'a9s', 'a8s', 'a7s', 'a6s', 'a5s', 'a4s', 'a3s', 'a2s',
          'ako', 'kk', 'kqs', 'kjs', 'kts', 'k9s', 'k8s', 'k7s', 'k6s', 'k5s', 'k4s', 'k3s', 'k2s',
          'aqo', 'kqo', 'qq', 'qjs', 'qts', 'q9s', 'q8s', 'q7s', 'q6s', 'q5s', 'q4s', 'q3s', 'q2s',
          'ajo', 'kjo', 'qjo', 'jj', 'jts', 'j9s', 'j8s', 'j7s', 'j6s', 'j5s', 'j4s', 'j3s', 'j2s',
          'ato', 'kto', 'qto', 'jto', 'tt', 't9s', 't8s', 't7s', 't6s', 't5s', 't4s', 't3s', 't2s',
          'a9o', 'k9o', 'q9o', 'j9o', 't9o', '99', '98s', '97s', '96s', '95s', '94s', '93s', '92s',
          'a8o', 'k8o', 'q8o', 'j8o', 't8o', '98o', '88', '87s', '86s', '85s', '84s', '83s', '82s',
          'a7o', 'k7o', 'q7o', 'j7o', 't7o', '97o', '87o', '77', '76s', '75s', '74s', '73s', '72s',
          'a6o', 'k6o', 'q6o', 'j6o', 't6o', '96o', '86o', '76o', '66', '65s', '64s', '63s', '62s',
          'a5o', 'k5o', 'q5o', 'j5o', 't5o', '95o', '85o', '75o', '65o', '55', '54s', '53s', '52s',
          'a4o', 'k4o', 'q4o', 'j4o', 't4o', '94o', '84o', '74o', '64o', '54o', '44', '43s', '42s',
          'a3o', 'k3o', 'q3o', 'j3o', 't3o', '93o', '83o', '73o', '63o', '53o', '43o', '33', '32s',
          'a2o', 'k2o', 'q2o', 'j2o', 't2o', '92o', '82o', '72o', '62o', '52o', '42o', '32o', '22',
        ],
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for Java/JDK:

```
code/premium-poker-tools-api [master] » java --version
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

When I look in my Java Control Panel, it says that I'm up to date.

I'm not sure how to figure out which Selenium version or Chrome version I'm using. For Chrome, if I open up Chrome and go to "About Google Chrome" it says `74.0.3729.169`, the up to date one, and I assume my tests are using that same version.

Comment: Update the question with the log messages within `Users/adamzerner/.npm/_logs/2019-05-23T19_47_08_016Z-debug.log
code/premium-poker-tools [master●]`

Comment: @DebanjanB Just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This log message...

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  58502
```

and the subsequent error message...

```
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance i.e. **ChromeDriver** though initiated but was unable to communicate with the **WebBrowsing** i.e. **Chrome** session.

---

Some more details about the:

- *Selenium* version.
- *JDK* version.
- *Selenium Server* mode (Standalone/Grid).
- *ChromeDriver* version.
- *Chrome* version.

Would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However as you have mentioned *"1, 2, and 3 get logged out, but not 4 or 5"*, possibly the issue stems out from the following code block:

```
equityCalculator
  .waitForElementVisible('@app', 50000, function () {
    console.log(4);
    browser.resizeWindow(1440, 852, function () {
      console.log(5);
      done();
    });
  })
```

---

### Reason

As per the discussion [Connection refused! Is selenium server started nightwatch on edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550626/connection-refused-is-selenium-server-started-nightwatch-on-edge/52552339#52552339) your main issue seems to be **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [ChromeDriver v74.0](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version to *Chrome v74* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v74.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Outro

['Connection refused! Is selenium server started?\n' while running Nightwatch.js tests against Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162892/connection-refused-is-selenium-server-started-n-while-running-nightwatch-js/50168743#50168743)

---

### Resolution

`updating` **npm** resolved the issue (as per OP's comments)

```
npm update
```